# Responsive table html,css

Tags: html, css

I have this css style for responsive table. it works as expected in firefox but not in chrome.

In chrome all the text mixed, and it seems that their is a layers.

what is the problem in the code that it works on firefox but not in chrome?

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table,
  thead,
  tbody,
  th,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block;
  }

  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }

  tr {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

  td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 50%;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: right;
  }

  td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    right: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  /*
  Label the data
  */
  td:before {
    content: attr(data-title);
  };
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>title 1</th>
      <th>title 2</th>
      <th>title 3</th>
      <th>title 4</th>
      <th>title 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="title1">
        text
      </td>
      <td data-title="title2">
        text
      </td>
      <td data-title="title3">
        text
      </td>
      <td data-title="title4">
        text
      </td>
      <td data-title="title5">
        text
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

In the preview it seems ok in chrome byt if I create new simple html file with the table in  the body it look very bad.
I understand that I need add something to the css or to the body but I dont know what.
This is how it looks like when I make the screen width small then  800px

[image]

Comment: Just as a heads up I have used this in the past. It requires jQuery but I have personally converted it to not use jQuery so it can be done and works well. http://gergeo.se/RWD-Table-Patterns/?utm_source=Front-end+Dev+Weekly&utm_campaign=2a5acde570-Front_end_Dev_Weekly_Issue_96_9_2014&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_c6dafce16b-2a5acde570-124910645

Comment: working great here Chrome v45 same as FFv41

Comment: in 3 computers.I checked it. On stackoverflow "run code snippet" it looks great but if I create simple page with
<html>
<style>
</style>
<body>
</body>
</html>

It looks very bad!

Comment: Are you using a doctype?

Comment: @Rob no but when I added this it sole the problem!!!

Comment: always add Doctype ;)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<html><head><style></style></head><body></body></html>`, since style tag needs to be in the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments it was found you were missing a doctype. A doctype is required of all modern web pages. Without one, you are in "quirks mode" and things like margin and padding and all kinds of things do not follow [the W3C box model](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/box.html).

Adding this to the very first line keeps all browsers in "standards mode"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

[Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/)